# IPv6 superuser ports

Tags: linux, ipv6, ipv4

Does IPv6 have the 0-1024 superuser requirements for ports? I saw in the changelog for Linux 4.11 that they added a sysctl option to change it, but it only lists it under IPv4.

Also does Open/FreeBSD have that restriction in IPv6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These ports are for TCP/UDP, which are protocols running on top of IP. So things should be same whatever version of IP you are using.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It's confusing that the option is hidden in the IPv4 area (`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_unprivileged_port_start`) instead of in a different directory for TCP and UDP. I will test it when I get access to a system with IPv6 enabled in the kernel.